# Poweroff Issue in Ubuntu 14.10 on Lenovo Z570

Tags: 14.04, shutdown, lenovo, battery

I just switched to using ubuntu from windows. I installed **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS** On my [Lenovo z570](http://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-ideapad-z570/specs/) laptop and everything works fine except for the issue with the Poweroff. When i shutdown the system, I end up on the shutdown screen :

[image]

I waited for almost 10-15 minutes but nothing happened. **I also tried pressing the power button but even that did not work**. Finally i had to remove the battery from the laptop to switch it off.

**NOTE :** I also tried issuing the **poweroff** command form terminal but that does not work either. It has the same issue.

**Terminal Command :**

```
prince@DevilsBlackbox:~$ sudo poweroff
[sudo] password for prince:
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the reboot problem: sudo reboot --force
To solve the shutdown problem: sudo poweroff --force

Comment: While this may seem to work, it's not a good solution, because it will halt the system regardless of open resources like file systems, that may need to be brought to a consistent state.

Comment: Does not work..